# Javascript return true not working / breaking script

Tags: javascript, validation, return-value

```
  function validator(field_value, field) {
            var name = document.getElementById('facility_Name').value;
            var region = document.getElementById('facility_Region').value;
            var state = document.getElementById('facility_State').value;
            var county = document.getElementById('facility_County').value;
            if (name == null || name == "") {
                $("p#validator_error").append('<a href="#Facility_Details">Click here complete the <i>Name</i> field</a>');
                $('#validation_modal').modal('show');
                return false;
            }
            if (region == null || region == "") {
                $("p#validator_error").append('<a href="#Facility_Details">Click here complete the <i>Region</i> field</a>');
                $('#validation_modal').modal('show');
                return false;
            }
            if (state == null || state == "") {
                $("p#validator_error").append('<a href="#Facility_Details">Click here complete the <i>State</i> field</a>');
                $('#validation_modal').modal('show');
                return false;
            }
            if (county == null || county == "") {
                $("p#validator_error").append('<a href="#Facility_Details">Click here complete the <i>County</i> field</a>');
                $('#validation_modal').modal('show');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        $('button#submitbutton').click(function () {
            window.console.log('upload started');
            //Check for Facility Details
            return validator();
// then do more stuff including an Ajax call
});
```

This should be a simple validation function? It works very well when one of the four fields is not entered into the boxes. That doesn't seem to be the problem. However when all the field are entered, the script just breaks at "return validator();" and doesn't throw any kind of error or it doesn't complete the rest of the script. Using "validator();" doesn't work either?

Comment: It should either be executed or throw an error. Did you check your console? Could you reproduce this problem in JSFiddle?

Comment: Why not put a debugger and step in?

Comment: Remove the parameters in your `function validator(field_value, field)`

Comment: I removed the parameters in validator(). Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script breaks at the "validator();" because it doesn't exists.
You have defined the function with parameters, for your validation procedure.
Try removing parameters from function and use as:

`if(validator()){// do stuff}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the return value in if condition to continue further. Something like below.

```
 if(validator()){
 more stuff including Ajax call
}else{
}
```

See about return here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return